# Encontrando Heróis Desconhecidos no Stack Overflow usando o Data Explorer

Tags: sql

Eu sei que não há nenhum [Heroi Desconhecido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/51/unsung-hero) aqui no SOPT, mas sei que existem vários no SOEN. Minha intenção é ordenar a porcentagem de respostas aceitas sem votos das pessoas que possuem essa medalha. E por isso tentei criar um SQL para o [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/). Mas não conheço SQL e tentei apenas juntar diversos exemplos e tentar verificar se conseguia.

A query que tentei (acho que é o mais próximo que cheguei):

```
SELECT TOP 100
    Id as [User Link],
    count(a.Id) as [Respostas Aceitas],
select
    sum(CASE WHEN a.Score = 0 then 1 else 0 end)*1000 / count(a.Id) / 10.0 as [Porcentagem]
from
    Users 
    inner join
    Posts q
    inner join
    Posts a
    on a.Id = q.AcceptedAnswerId and q.AcceptedAnswerId = Users.UserID
where
      a.CommunityOwnedDate is null
      and a.postTypeId = 2
order by Porcentagem
```

Mensagem de Erro:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.

Comment: Qual o resultado da query? Pode colocar um link para seu teste no DE?

Comment: @brasofilo, não tenho como colocar o link, porque não consegui logar lá com o facebook e também acho que ele não salva uma `query` com erro.

Comment: Acertei a sintaxe da sua consulta, mas tem um join que não entendi. p.e: `(q.AcceptedAnswerId = Users.UserID)`. Segue o link: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/218881. Ainda falta algumas coisas para acertar.

Comment: Você quer simplesmente quem tem a medalha? Se for, tem uma tabela `Badges`, basta olhar nela.

Comment: Amigo,qual banco de dados?

Comment: @bfavaretto expliquei melhor [nesse comentário](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29441/encontrando-her%c3%b3is-desconhecidos-no-stack-overflow-usando-o-data-explorer#comment55066_29579)

Comment: Ok, editei a pergunta acrescentando essa informação. Sempre prefira editar a pergunta a acrescentar informações em comentários, pois nada garante que um moderador obsessivo-compulsivo chegue e limpe todos os comentários da pergunta (não olha pra mim...) :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Como sugeriu o @bfavaretto, se sua intenção fosse apenas retornar os usuários que possuem esta medalha, bastaria olhar diretamente na tabela Badges:

```
select u.DisplayName from Users u
    inner join Badges b on u.Id = b.UserId
    where b.Name like 'Unsung Hero'
```

Os nomes das medalhas não são traduzidos no banco - daí o uso do nome original ("Unsung Hero"). Para ver quais seriam os possíveis candidatos a esta medalha (isto é, com pelo menos 10 respostas aceitas), ordenados pelo percentual, a query abaixo deve funcionar:

```
select  TOP 100 
        a.OwnerUserId as UserId,
        sum(case when a.Score = 0 then 0 else 1 end) as [Respostas Com Votos],  
        sum(case when a.Score = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as [Respostas Sem Votos],
        sum(CASE WHEN a.Score = 0 then 1 else 0 end)*1000 / count(a.Id) / 10.0 as [Percentual de Sem Votos]
    from
        Posts q
      inner join
        Posts a
      on a.Id = q.AcceptedAnswerId
    where
          a.CommunityOwnedDate is null
      and a.OwnerUserId != q.OwnerUserId
      and a.postTypeId = 2      
    group by a.OwnerUserId
    having count(a.Id) >= 10
    order by 4 desc
```

Comment: Minha intenção é ordenar a porcentagem de respostas aceitas sem votos das pessoas que possuem essa medalha. Peço desculpas se não ficou claro na pergunta.

Comment: Editei a resposta, incluindo uma query que deve funcionar para seus propósitos :)

Comment: Só um comentário (*nah vá, é mermo*). Ambas as consultas demoraram MUITO pra executar. Ou a estrutura deve ser bem capenga (o que eu duvido) ou a quantidade de registros deve ser maciça.

Comment: Coloquei um limite de TOP 100 só pra não demorar taaanto no SOen.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto ou, sendo um serviço aberto, a prioridade de execução das queries dever ser extremamente baixa.

Comment: Verdade. Queria saber como esse tipo de prioridade é feito, mas deixa pra outra ocasião